# Formula for quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following expression

$$x^T (A+B)^{-1}x,\tag{1}$$

where $x$ is a column vector, and both $A$ and $B$ are invertible ($A$ is diagonal if this helps).

Is there some formula such that $(1)$ is reformulated into

$$f(A) + g(B),$$

where $f$ and $g$ are some functions?

The motivation is to decompose $(1)$ into the addition of two parts, where one part depends only on $A$ (and $x$), while the other term depends only on $B$ (and $x$).

Comment: FYI you can get the desired effect of $(1)$ by using the command `\tag{1}` after your expression.

Answer (score 0):

No. If such $f(A,x)$ and $g(B,x)$ exist, then $x^T(A+B_1)^{-1}x-x^T(A+B_2)^{-1}x$ does not depend on $A$, because it is equal to $g(B_1,x)-g(B_2,x)$. However, this is not the case in reality. E.g. when $x$ is a unit vector,
\begin{aligned}
&x^T(I+0)^{-1}x-x^T(I+I)^{-1}x=\frac12,\\
\ne\ &x^T(2I+0)^{-1}x-x^T(2I+I)^{-1}x=\frac16.\\
\end{aligned}